# Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::setReconnector()

Tags: php, symfony, laravel

I am creating laravel 4 login system using "Sentry by Cartalyst". Everything is running well in my localhost, 
But, when I upload to my shared hosting. I got some following error.

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::setReconnector()

I see an error in bootsrtap/compiled.php

```
 $app = $this->app;
$connection->setCacheManager(function () use($app) {
return $app['cache'];
});
$connection->setPaginator(function () use($app) {
return $app['paginator'];
});
$connection->setReconnector(function ($connection) {
$this->reconnect($connection->getName());
});
```

Please help me to fix this eror.

Comment: The method setReconnector() isn't present in MySqlConnection class. What Laravel version is it?

Comment: I am using laravel 4.2.

Comment: I am also using Laravel 4.2 with the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Try making sure that composer has installed AND updated the vendor specific files on your shared hosting: run 'composer install' & 'composer update'